# Use depth texture in compute shader

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to use a depth texture in a compute shader.

The depth texture is created with the format `VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT` and with the usage `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

The problem is that it seems that this combination of parameters is not supported, I have this warning: `vkCreateImageView(): pCreateInfo->format VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT with tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL does not support usage that includes VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

Except this message, the program is working well and the compute shader successfully read the depth texture.

Is this possible to read depth texture in compute shader ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to read a 32-bit normalized depth image in a compute shader. Just not *in your implementation*.

Vulkan permits an implementation to refuse certain combinations of image formats and usages. They can refuse some formats entirely, while restricting other formats to only specific usages. As such, unless the format+usage combination you intend to use is on the Vulkan specification's list of required functionality, you *must* query support for it.

Vulkan doesn't require that implementations allow you to use `D32` images as storage images. Therefore, you must check to see if a particular implementation provides this functionality.

Comment: It seems that no format can support storage usage and depth attachment usage. A solution could be to copy the depth image to a buffer then to a color image (with format R32_SFLOAT) but it's a big process to simply use a depth image.

Comment: how do you query for those combinations? `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties` doesn't appear to be capable of querying support for usages.

Comment: @whn: That's what the `VkFormatFeatureFlags` are. For example, `VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT` maps to `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

Comment: Okay so you would just do `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties` with `format = VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT`, and `pFormatProperties = &VkFormatProperties {.optimalTilingFeatures = VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT}` to query for support then?

Comment: @whn yes but the test is `formatProperties.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_STORAGE_IMAGE_BIT`because `optimalTilingFeatures` can be concatenation of multiple values